# Problem in JSR223 script, Provider processor

Tags: groovy, jmeter

Problem in JSR223 script, Provider processor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.regex.Matcher) values: [callbackUri, java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&) region=0,537 lastmatch=]]
Possible solutions: put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), get(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), dump(), any()

Error in groovy code. The error goes like this "Script144.run(Script144.groovy:2) ~[?:?]"

Trying to fetch a value in from the response of previous GET request.

```
def redirect = prev.getRedirectLocation()
def redirectQuery = new URI(redirect).query
def callbackUriMatch = (redirectQuery =~ /(?<=callbackUri=).*(? 
=&)/)[0]
vars.put("callbackUri", callbackUriMatch)
```

The callbackUri is supposed to fetch the value from the previous call. But it is failing to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The main point of this "line" is `=~` which is Groovy's [match operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-operators.html#_match_operator), it applies a [Regular Expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/groovy.html) to the redirect query string in order to get `callbackUri` parameter from it.

Try amending this line to remove the line break from it:

```
def callbackUriMatch = (redirectQuery =~ /(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&)/)[0]
```

If this doesn't help - try adding some logging by [putting `log.info()`](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) statements to print the variable values to *jmeter.log* file, like:

```
def redirect = prev.getRedirectLocation()
log.info('Redirect: ' + redirect)
def redirectQuery = new URI(redirect).query
log.info('Redirect query: ' + redirectQuery)
def callbackUriMatch = (redirectQuery =~ /(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&)/)[0]
vars.put("callbackUri", callbackUriMatch)
```

This way you will be able to see some source data for matchers and get some clues regarding how to fix the issue. If you won't be able to do this yourself - update the question with the actual redirect URL so we could come up with the proper regular expression.

Comment: http://xyz?state=lTHEZdLF6cooiOw8SWZe7NhDAhDzyzOQI8r1CwePELs7OnQ9KC-gLCkujk-4UW6qXciNTLguDhk61NsWs8pREuVPAXISS2qaPC1tWPGUTcuwSlxkZwFgyzq_tkn9y4xqTlsAjJAc10q-2uyMYVLRtPn_0ACdVx1_zRTK6XXkHrRbx0py0SXUW-7ygFoffEfzf-TRGrqyVCv3jrWUiPflKRs128F9BVIUNk0cfzJwaN6i54bgcN1fB7sksxd4nJ0ocQaJ1mJKrNz2jtKNkbVN-_ebGg8azIRnUmZAWUoXZgIPLQAUzqPNXyJ63G0Dac9WyqnY3g

Comment: I don't see any `callbackUri` in this line

Comment: http://xyz=F96F63F6-E691-499B-A952-33857877A38D&callbackUri=http%3A%2F%2xyz%2Fidentityserver%2Fcore%2Fsignin-emishealth%3Fstate%3DlTHEZdLF6cooiOw8SWZe7NhDAhDzyzOQI8r1CwePELs7OnQ9KC-gLCkujk-4UW6qXciNTLguDhk61NsWs8pREuVPAXISS2qaPC1tWPGUTcuwSlxkZwFgyzq_tkn9y4xqTlsAjJAc10q-2uyMYVLRtPn_0ACdVx1_zRTK6XXkHrRbx0py0SXUW-7ygFoffEfzf-TRGrqyVCv3jrWUiPflKRs128F9BVIUNk0cfzJwaN6i54bgcN1fB7sksxd4nJ0ocQaJ1mJKrNz2jtKNkbVN-_ebGg8azIRnUmZAWUoXZgIPLQAUzqPNXyJ63G0Dac9WyqnY3g&applicationName=emis_mobile

Comment: So far I can suggest only this amendment: `def callbackUriMatch = (reqirectQuery =~ "&callbackUri=(.*)")[0][1]`. If you're not comfortable with Groovy - you can consider using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) instead. See [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables) for more details if needed

Comment: WIll take a look. Thanks a lot

Comment: Digging deep in to the errors, I found this. 

Problem in JSR223 script, Provider processor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterVariables.put() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.regex.Matcher) values: [callbackUri, java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(?<=callbackUri=).*(?=&) region=0,537 lastmatch=]]
Possible solutions: put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String), get(java.lang.String), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object), wait(), any(), dump(). 
What does this signify?

Comment: Still stuck here.